# Variable local vs variable devuelta por un método en Kotlin, ¿qué es más eficiente o cuál es la mejor forma?

Tags: android, kotlin, buenas-prácticas

Apenas estoy empezando con Kotlin y me asalta una duda.

En un Fragmento obtengo los elementos de la vista llamando a un método `getViewBinding()`.

Tengo por ejemplo un `TextView` el cual necesito modificar en varias partes del Fragmento, por lo que necesitaría tener acceso a él desde cualquier parte de la clase. Eso me lo permite `getViewBinding()` o bien puedo definir una variable local al estilo `private lateinit var mTextView`.

Mi duda es saber qué sería más eficiente y/o mejor práctica entre esto:

```
class SyncFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentSyncBinding>() {
    private lateinit var mTextView: ZoomTextView

    override fun init(viewBinding: ViewBinding) {
        val fontSize = sp?.getString("font_size", "18")!!.toFloat()
        val fontFamily = String.format(
            Locale("es"),
            "fonts/%s",
            sp.getString("font_name", "robotoslab_regular.ttf")
        )
        val tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(requireActivity().assets, fontFamily)

        /*
           ¿Es mejor tres llamadas a getViewBinding()
        */

        getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize)
        getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.typeface = tf
        getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.text = "Asignamos el texto"
    }

}
```

O esto:

```
import org.deiverbum.app.utils.ZoomTextView

class SyncFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentSyncBinding>() {
    private lateinit var mTextView: ZoomTextView

    override fun init(viewBinding: ViewBinding) {
        val fontSize = sp?.getString("font_size", "18")!!.toFloat()
        val fontFamily = String.format(
            Locale("es"),
            "fonts/%s",
            sp.getString("font_name", "robotoslab_regular.ttf")
        )
        val tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(requireActivity().assets, fontFamily)

        mTextView = getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize)
        mTextView.tvZoomable.typeface = tf
        mTextView.text = "Asignamos el texto"
    }

}
```

`BaseFragment` es una clase abstracta que he definido para usarla con varios fragmentos:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T> : Fragment() {
    private var viewBinding: ViewBinding? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentTodayBinding? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentTodayBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        //    

        viewBinding = constructViewBinding()
        viewBinding?.let { init(it) }
        return viewBinding?.root
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun getViewBinding(): T = viewBinding as T

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewBinding = null
    }

    abstract fun constructViewBinding(): ViewBinding
    abstract fun init(viewBinding: ViewBinding)
}
```

Algo que me hace dudar es que si uso la primera forma, no necesito importar la clase del `TextView`:

```
import org.deiverbum.app.utils.ZoomTextView
```

Comment: La respuesta sería: **Depende**. De la implementación de `getBinding()` y los pasos intermedios hasta llegar a la vista y la complejidad que tengan. Si alguno de ellos es costoso, lo lógico es guardar la referencia en una variable.

Comment: Para saber más al respecto, de dónde proviene la función `getViewBinding()`? No logro encontrarla en el buscador. Sí encontré [algo más interesante](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). Por cierto, la documentación dice que la clase [`BaseFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/leanback/app/BaseFragment) es obsoleta.

Comment: @Mateo gracias por tus comentarios. `getViewBinding()` está definido en la clase `BaseFragment`, pero OJO, no es la clase obsoleta a la que haces referencia, sino una clase abstracta que he definido para usarla como base de varios fragmentos. Ahora voy a poner una parte de `BaseFragment` en la pregunta. En cuanto a vinculación de vista, ya lo estoy usando, de hecho, la llamada a `getViewBinding()` la usa.

Comment: Tal vez está pregunta sea basada en opiniones. Si, llamar a una función es más caro que tener en caché una variable. ¿Realmente deberías preocuparte por eso? Para evitar llamarla seguidamente puedes usar `apply`. Puedes ver algunos ejemplos [aquí](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html). Por cierto, el unchecked cast hace que ignores la posibilidad de que `viewBinding` sea `null` pudiendo obtener un error. No quiero decir que esté mal, pero hay que tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: Cuando se utiliza `ViewBinding` es para evitar en general crear variables para cada view que se define en el layout XML, así que considero innecesario definir una nueva variable para almacenar el `TextView`. Asimismo, como señala Mateo en otro comentario, es idiomatico en Kotlin hacer `getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable.apply {}` para evitar repetir `getViewBinding().include.tvZoomable`.